# how to differentiate between top nav menu and body nav menu in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design, nav

I am currently using `wp_nav_menu` to generate my nav menu in top and body. In header.php, I have used

```
        <?php if(has_nav_menu('body-nav')) {
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav', 'items_wrap' => '<select class="mobile-menu">%3$s', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' => 'null'));
} else {
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav', 'items_wrap' => '<select class="mobile-menu">%3$s</select>', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' => 'null'));       
} ?>

<?php if(has_nav_menu('top-nav')) {
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s</select>', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' => 'null'));
} else {
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav', 'items_wrap' => '<select class="mobile-menu">%3$s</select>', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' => 'null'));           
}?>
```

It works and shows fine, but when the browser (Firefox) is in restore down or in small position, then two menus become/combine in a dropdown box. I need to differentiate between top and body nav menu when the browser is in restore position. i.e It is needed to show top menu for top menu bar as well as to show body menu for body menu bar in full screen and also in browser restore/small position. I have tried a lot. There is no solution. When I try to put drop-down box, it also combines with top menu and body menu. How to differentiate this type of issue. Please see [this site](http://letsassistblog.com/) in restore down/small position. Does anyone knows this type of issue?

Answer (score 1):

This "issue" is caused by your theme .
More specifically , the `custom.js` located at `http://letsassistblog.com/wp-content/themes/thegossip/lib/scripts/custom.js`  ( and media queries )

lines 16

```
/////////////////////////////////////// Mobile Navigation Menu ///////////////////////////////////////
jQuery("<option />", {"selected": "selected", "value": "", "text": navigationText}).prependTo(".nav select");
jQuery(".nav .menu a").each(function() {
var el = jQuery(this);
var padding = "";
for (var i = 0; i < el.parentsUntil('div > ul').length - 1; i++)
padding += "-";
jQuery("<option />", {
"value" : el.attr("href"),
"text" : padding + el.text()
}).appendTo(".nav select");
});
jQuery(".nav select").change(function() {
window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Now , I wrote "issue" with quotes , because this is actually a ( very ) desirable feature called " [Responsive Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) " or `RWD`. it adapts your menus for easy viewing on mobile devices ..

Now - regarding some real issues on your site - I am surprised it works . 
You are jQuery 3 times ... and 2 different versions of it .

I would look at the code and make some corrections to the script loading ...

**EDIT I** - Not really clear on what you want to do from your comment - But I already showed you here above the code that produces the menu. this line :

```
jQuery(".nav .menu a").each(function()
```

Is taking all the `.menu` class `a` element inside `.nav` and turns to an option select .

Since both your `body-nav` and `top-nav` id´s share both the same `.nav` class - the script applies to both.

If you want only ONE to be affected - Change the selector in that line .
e.g.

```
 jQuery("#top-nav .menu a").each(function() // or body-nav
```

or

```
 jQuery("#top-nav .nav .menu a").each(function()// or body-nav
```

If you want to disable it completely for both - Just delete it or comment out .

Regarding your remark on `jQuery` - 
Your site loads 3 different libraries from 3 different sources and 2 versions .
`jQuery` should only be loaded ONCE to avoid conflicts and there is no reason to load 3 times ( except extreme compatibility issues ) .

It is not the same library used many times - that has no sense in jQuery ( or any library for that matter - this is the whole point of a library.. ).

Comment: Yea,same Jquery library is used many times. And for this type issue, this assignment I will take look later. But in this moment, I need to to menu in top nav as well as body nav in mobile/responsive position soon in this design.I take a solution for this with    @media only screen and (max-width: 100px) and mobile menu display inline block as well as for full screen, menu display none. But here it is not currect solution.It arises a problem in SEO. And for that I am looking for another solution like how to show top nav menu as well as body nav menu in this design in full screen and in mobile.

Comment: 1 - I already showed you where this is happening .. please read my update if you do not understand .. 2 - You are `loading` jQuery 3 times and with 3 different versions. This is not the same jQuery library used many times. It is different jQuery used . And also - Jquery needs to be loaded ONE time only regardeless of how you use it .

Comment: I want not only ONE to be affected, I want both to be affected. In custom.js I have edited with    jQuery("#top-nav .menu a").each(function() for top nav menu while jQuery2("#top-nav .menu a").each(function() for body nav menu to show top bar menu as well as body nav menu.

Comment: @user2995268 - I am sorry. I am sure that in your head you know what you want - but your comments ( and OP ) are really unclear to me . Can you describe what you want to do ?? if you do not want this behaviour -just disable it ! .

Comment: Ok,I describe fully.Now in full screen the top nav menu(Home, About,..) and body nav menu(Home, Social Stuff,...) show finely.ok. When the browser is in responsive position/restore position, then there is showed a select box/combo box of menu of top nav menu and body nav menu instead of showing ul li for both menu and it also combines two menu bars in one select box. But I need to show top nav menu in top navigation and also need to show body nav menu in body in ul li or select box in responsive position/browser restore position.Have you understood what I need.

Comment: And ofcourse nav menu's select box is coming from costom js.I have tried with   jQuery("#top-nav .menu a").each(function() {} for top nav menu bar and for body nav menu bar I have tried with    jQuery2("#top-nav .menu a").each(function() {} in my local server. It shows two drop-down box. Ok. But in both two drop-down boxes, it is showed the list of top nav menu bar.

Comment: I have used in PHP open source Wordpress. For responsive position/browser restore position, I have used the code like    <?php if(has_nav_menu('top-nav')){     wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav', 'items_wrap' => '<select>%3$s</select>', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'top-mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' => 'null'));}if(has_nav_menu('body-nav')) {   wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'body-nav', 'items_wrap' => '<select>%3$s</select>', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'body-mobile-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'fallback_cb' =>'null'));}?>

Comment: And Thank you for replying me again. Thanks.

Comment: I try to reply but the issue is not wordpres related.. as far as I understand ( and I do realize now that it is not much ) it is jQuery and JS problem.. no matter how you will register the menus - the  script will target them... I suggest that either you open a new question and tag with `JS` `javascript` or `jQuery` - or try to edit tags on and title on this one ..